# How to respond to crown scrolling for Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, watchkit, apple-watch

I have a slider control in my watch app, but I'd like the user to use the crown to scroll through larger numbers, instead of tapping on the increase/decrease buttons a hundred times. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't respond to the crown scrolling.  This is from an Apple evangelist on https://devforums.apple.com/thread/254540?tstart=15

> From a Watch app's point of view, a wearer who's using the digital
>   crown is indistinguishable from a wearer who's scrolling the interface
>   with a finger. There are no scroll callbacks for either case.

Answer (score 0):

The [Apple Watch Videos](http://www.apple.com/watch/guided-tours/) show how the crown works. Watch the first video *Welcome to Apple Watch*, at 01:58 the digital crown is explained. At 02:43 it shows a stepper.

Looks like the crown makes stepping possibly much faster than in +/- 1 steps.

Comment: But that control doesn't come out of the box, or am I missing it? All I see is the slider control.